# How to correctly add nested divs

Tags: html, css

For UI designing (Ok, I'm not a designer) I've sectioned a div into different areas, corresponding to subdivs. The first is:

This is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4nvU/1/) but I introduce my code in here:

```
<div id="outer">
        <div id="parametros"></div>
        <div id="resultados"></div>
</div>
```

But I also sectioned resultados:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="parametros"></div>

    <div id="resultados">
        <div id="graficos">
            <div id="bars"></div>
            <div id="fx"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="loquerealmenteimporta"></div>  
    </div>

</div>
```

I wrote this simple CSS for sectioning:

```
#parametros {

  float:left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}

#resultados {

  float:right;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

      #graficos {
        float: top;
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        color: yellow;
      }

      #loquerealmenteimporta {
        float: bottom;
        height: 240px;
        width: 100%;
        color: purple;
      }
```

And gave each div a different `backgorund-color` to identify them. However, I can't get the inner `divs` to get its custom color, as their outer `div`'s assigned `background-color` remains.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the inner elements a [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) property - the color property sets the foreground (text) colour, not the background.

As well as this, your inner elements are currently inheriting the background colour from their respective parent elements, which is what made it appear to you as though it was overriding your inner element CSS.

If you'd like to give them their own background colour, use [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) instead of `color`, e.g

```
#graficos {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#loquerealmenteimporta {
  height: 240px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

BTW: `float` does not have `top` or `bottom` values, so you should remove them.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/a4nvU/3/)</kbd>

Comment: It was stupid mistake, thanks. If I got wrong the float properties, how can I manage having 3 or more divs stacked?

Comment: Well,yes :) I think there will be more sophisticated CSS properties, styles, but so far, that's how then, isn't it?

Comment: Overlaps, for example

Comment: How many did you plan on stacking on top of each other like that?

Comment: I just meant for any example

Comment: Yeah, you'd allocate different heights in percentages. I used 33.3/.4 as it's 100% divided by three, you'd use 25% for four if you wanted it to be equal, or give them all different heights as long as it matches under or equal to 100%

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49792/discussion-between-diegoaguilar-and-null)

Comment: @diegoaguilar I would chat, but it's 7:30am here and I haven't slept yet :/ If you leave a long comment or something, I can reply when I get up later today?

Comment: Sure, I understand :) My only doubt is how I can force a div to actually be first, second,3rd, etc?

Comment: @diegoaguilar This may be of some use for this - http://tanalin.com/en/articles/css-block-order/, also http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/floatclear